# Trying To Redirect With home_controller.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

this is a bit of a newbie question, but I am trying to redirect to my blog through my ruby controller.  The blog is located at /public/blog, but I am just getting a blank screen at my /index right now, with no HTML content.

Here is my home_controller.rb file:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :dash_board_path

  def index
    if current_user
      redirect_to @dash_board
    #else
    # render :layout => "home"  
    end   
  end  

  def blog
    current_path = request.fullpath
    redirect_path = current_path.gsub("/blog" , "/index")
    render :text => redirect_path and return
    redirect_to redirect_path
  end  
end
```

I should also add - the blog is meant to be viewed at the site root - mysite.com should have the blog on it.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Redirect from `index to blog` or `blog to index`. You are saying `index to blog` in question and your code looks like you are trying for `blog to index`.

Comment: I am trying to display the contents of my public/blog folder (which is my blog) on the root of the domain.  So, when a visitor goes to mysite.com they will see the contents of my blog.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the last line in your blog method is being executed, since you've got the `and return` after rendering the text.  So the redirect isn't actually occurring.

Comment: Hmmm - I tried removing "and return", but I still get the same result - blank screen at the domain root

Comment: It may be because you're rendering text out the browser in the previous line.  Normally you don't render and return in the same controller action.